# linker error after changed the type of c++ project from x86 to x64

Tags: c++, visual-studio, x86, 64-bit

I had a project which was compiled and liked well, but I need to linked it with a 64 bit library and I tried to change the type of project to 64 and now the project doesn't linked correctly.

The error that I am getting is:

```
Error   1   error LNK1112: module machine type 'X86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'   \createDLL.obj
```

checking output, I can see that the linker is called in this way:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\link.exe /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /OUT:"..\Debug\createDLL.exe" /INCREMENTAL /NOLOGO kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /manifest:embed /DEBUG /PDB:"..\Debug\createDLL.pdb" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /TLBID:1 /DYNAMICBASE:NO /IMPLIB:"..\Debug\createDLL.lib" /MACHINE:X64 /SAFESEH Debug\createDLL.obj
```

apparently the linker is looking for an obj which compiled for 64 but it can not find it

How can I set the compiler to compile for x64?

I am using VS 2012

Comment: Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding? I'm not sure about the x64 side, but cross-compiling for MS Windows CE requires quite some cleanup to the project file. In VS2005 (not sure about VS2012), start with setting the dirs for output files and intermediate files to separate paths for each platform and configuration. Then, replace any leftover paths in compiler and linker settings with $(OutDir) and $(IntDir). This should get you started and avoid mixups.

Answer (score 0):

1)Try to get 32 bit version of the library if possible.

2)Check the options in **Project->Properties->Configuration properties->Linker** . Check settings in **General** ,**Input** & **Advanced** pages mainly in it.Should solve your problem